# PHP $_POST data empty

Tags: php, javascript, html

So my website needs updating by tonight and I'm a PHP noob. I'm trying to submit a simple form via e-mail. When I get the e-mail though, the $_POST fields are not populated and the message body comes out as: "Name: Email: Organization: Role:" with no data. Any ideas? Thanks.

HTML file:

```
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm" action="submit_contact.php"></div>
        <div class="modal hide fade in" id="contactModal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                <h3>Submit form</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div style='display:none'></div>

                <fieldset>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="name" type="text" name="name" maxlength="75" />
                            <p class="help-block" id="name_error"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">E-mail</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="email" type="text" name="email" maxlength="75" />
                            <p class="help-block" id="email_error"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Organization</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="organization" type="text" name="organization" maxlength="75" />
                            <p class="help-block" id="organization_error"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Role</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select name="occupation" id="id_occupation">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="MD">Medical Devices - Sales & Marketing</option>
<option value="MO">Medical Devices - Other</option>
<option value="MD">Physician</option>
<option value="OT">Other</option>
</select>
                            <p class="help-block" id="occupation_error"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="height:30px">
                <a name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" id="contactSubmit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#">
                    Submit
                </a>
                <p style="text-align: left; margin-top:6px;" id="contactFormStatus"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
$('#contactSubmit').on('click', function(e){
  // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Find form and submit it
    $('#contactForm').submit();
});
</script>
```

submit_contact.php:

```
<?php 
$ToEmail = 'xxx@xxx.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "\nEmail: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "\nOrganization: ".$_POST["organization"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "\nRole: ".$_POST["occupation"]."";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
```

Comment: Not a duplicate - really need this answered and had a typo in the original post that people responded to that threw them off.

Comment: What is the url of the site?

Comment: Not public right now - I created a test subfolder.

Comment: I don't get it. Why would you cancel the built in submit function of a button, just to trigger the same function with javascipt ?

Comment: Please do not post multiple questions on the same subject. Try to update your original question to provide better clarity on what it is you are having trouble with. And most of all. Have patience, we are not here to give you answers NOW.

Comment: have you tried echoing $MESSAGE_BODY t see what it holds before sending the email?

Comment: @Khez - sorry, just up against a deadline and frustrated after debugging this all day.

Comment: @adeneo - Because I'm a noob and not typically a web developer.

Comment: Start by removing the javascript, it does nothing, then in your PHP file simply write `print_r( $_POST )` and see what you've got.

Comment: Add `<input type="submit" value="submit" />` before `<a name="submit" type="submit"` and see if you get anything

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 - Same as the e-mail response - "Name: Email: Organization: Role:"

Comment: have you tried sending it without headers?

Comment: Don't think it submits at all without the JavaScript.

Comment: Headers - no help. print_r($_POST) prints "Array ( )".

Comment: If you're not redirected to submit_contact.php, it's not submitting, and you should use a button not an anchor for a submit button.

Comment: Thanks, but it is sending the e-mail. The fields just aren't populated and $_POST is empty.